# unity3d form.Addfield doesn't send variable to PHP file

Tags: c#, php, forms, unity-game-engine

I'm really stuck with something i don't see why it is not working.
My goal is to send a POST variable from unity to a php file. The php file is working fine and when i submit a POST with an regular HTML form it is working. But not when i send it from unity, then the php says `Notice: Undefined index:` 
Here is the code (i am using a example from unity itself)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class FormSender : MonoBehaviour
{

public string discipline;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Upload());
}

IEnumerator Upload()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("Discipline", discipline);

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("linktomyworkingphpfile.php", form);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }
}
}
```

And in my php file i retrieve it like this:

```
$discipline = $_POST['Discipline'];
```

(i don;t think it is in the php because with a regular HTML form it is working fine).
I really dont see what i am doing wrong.
Can someone help me??
Thnx

This is the example from the unity resource:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MyBehavior : public MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(Upload());
    }

    IEnumerator Upload() {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("myField", "myData");

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("linktomyworkingphpfile.php", form);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

the only difference i see is that the unity example has public monobehaviour? but when i do this it gives me a compile error: Unexpected symbol `public', expecting`type'

In my console it also shows the debug "Form upload complete!".

I am really puzzled here
Ps. the string i am sending for discipline is 100% correct (copy pasted, working in html form not through unity)

updated code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class FormSender : MonoBehaviour
{

public string discipline;

  void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Upload());
        StartCoroutine(GetText());
    }






    IEnumerator Upload()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("Discipline", discipline);

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/alchemywebinterface/unity/categories.php", form);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }
}

    IEnumerator GetText()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost/alchemywebinterface/unity/categories.php");
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Show results as text
            Debug.Log("TEXT = " + www.downloadHandler.text);

            // Or retrieve results as binary data
            byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
        }
    }
}
```

it outputs:

```
 TEXT = <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Discipline in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\AlchemyWebInterface\unity\categories.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
test textProduct categorie: Product Cat 1;Product categorie: Product Cat 2;Product categorie: Visualisatie;Product categorie: Simulatie;
```

and

```
Form upload complete!
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbName = "test";

    //make connection

    $conn = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

    $discipline = $_POST['Discipline'];
   // $discipline = "Virtual Experience";

    //Check Connection
    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }

echo ("test text");


    //$sqlCat = "SELECT distinct product_cat FROM product where discipline_naam='".$discipline."'"; 
    $sqlCat = "SELECT distinct product_cat FROM product";
    $resultCat = mysqli_query($conn ,$sqlCat);  

    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultCat) > 0){        //show data for each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCat)){
            echo "Product categorie: ".$row['product_cat'] . ";"; 

        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: Print something back to Unity from php and see if you get the data

Comment: I can receive the data in unity from php (reading uit sql tables) with the www class WWW data = new WWW ("link to php file.php");

Comment: Please update your question with your new code that prints to Unity and your Unity code you use to print the received data. I just want to make sure

Comment: i;ve updatet it

Comment: Sorry but no part of your `UnityWebRequest` code is printing the received data from php to Unity. You need to do that with `Debug.Log` and you also need to show what you are printing from your php script. A simple text is fine for this. Finally, show the output from the Editor Console tab. Without this, it is hard to help you since I am not sitting next to your pc

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTextBinaryData.html i have to do this i suppose?

Comment: I;ve updated it i think this is what you ment?

Comment: After the log, you don't need to post anything from else from `UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)` down. Just the log. Please post the php code too. While at it, simply echo a simple static text from the php and see if you will get it in Unity

Comment: Ok removed the irrelevant debug information, The php file is also posted (the querry with the $discipline  variable is de-actived for testing purposes, but when the variable comes through the notice from undefined variable has to go away isn't it?)

i've added echo ("test text"); to the php and " test text" shows up in the console from unity

Comment: Good sign. Now, try to echo  $discipline back to Unity

Comment: i've replaced the echo with echo ($discipline); but it is not showing up in the unity console

Comment: That's weird. Why not use the `WWW` API instead of `UnityWebRequest` then see what happens with the-same test

Comment: Yes it is weird indeed, i think it is like posting something without cookies in a webbrowser and then open it again in another tab then its empty. I am trying it with the WWW api now, when i fixed it i will let you know

Comment: The WWW api works without a problem. mayby it's something in the unitywebrequest? i believe it's quite new?

Comment: It was new in 5.3. Not anymore  but I suspect it is `UnityWebRequest`s fault. You cvan file for  bug report to notify Unity about the bug.